# Azure function binding ignore null values in map on serialization

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-queues

I am using **Azure-Functions**.
I have two functions, **funcA**, and **funcB**.

**funcA** has a **QueueOutput** for a message that contains a Map, into an **Azure Storage queue**.

This Map may contain null values.
**funcB** is triggered by messages from the same queue **QueueTrigger**.

The problem is that when **funcA** output a message that contains a Map with null values, **funcB** gets the message but all the null values and their keys disappear.

I have checked and the **Azure Storage queue** is being filled by **funcA** QueueOutput binding without the null valued keys in the first place, so this happens on serialization of the message by **funcA** **QueueOutput** binding.

Is there a way to force the binding to keep the null valued keys in the Map?
Maybe a custom serialize/de-serialize?

Comment: Can you provide the code that you tried for your Function app?